# Localization using a prime ideal

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization

I'm approaching localization of rings using multiplicatively closed sets, and the obvious case of when we take the complementary of a prime ideal of a ring, that is always multiplicatively closed.

> The question at hand asks to prove that the ring $k[x,y]/(xy^2,x^2y)$ localized at $(x)$ is (or isn't) isomorphic to the ring $k[x]$ localized at $(x)$.

I think the second ring could be characterized as the ring of one-variable polynomials where the denominator, expressed as sum of monomials, needs to have a non zero constant, and the numerator can be whatever. I have trouble visualizing the first one. The quotient ring seems to describe the ring of polynomials in two variables, $x,y$, whose mixed terms can only be of degree one (So, just $xy$ and not higher powers). Localizing it to $(x)$ means in this case... What? That there can't be polynomials at denominator with all its monomials multiplying x? There needs to be at least an y, or a constant in there?

Comment: Also, if I'm right, is it the same for $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}$? If not, could someone please describe intuitively this ring?

Comment: I am not sure if there is a nice way to characterize the ring you are describing but what you writing seems to be correct.

Comment: @WittyCatchphrase as long as $A$ is an integral domain (e.g. $k[x,y]$), $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ can be thought of as living inside the fraction field of $A$ (why?). So at least this gives a nice way of thinking about elements of $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ since elements of $\text{Frac}(A)$  just look like $\frac{a}{b}$ for $a \in A, b \in A - \{0\}$. Actually, by the def, $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ are those $\frac{a}{b}$ where $a \in A$ and $b \in A - \mathfrak{p}$. In your case, $f \notin (x,y)$ iff $f(0,0) \neq 0$.

Comment: Okok I thought there was something more to it, and that the two rings were indeed isomorphic and I just needed to find the right way to look at the first ring to define the isomorphism. I was wrong from the start, now I got it. Thank you!

Comment: In general, $(R/I)_{P/I}\simeq R_P/IR_P$. In your case $R=k[x,y]$, $I=(xy^2,x^2y)$ and $P=(x)$. Notice that $y$ becomes invertible in lozalization, so $IR_P=(x)R_P$. In our case $R_P/IR_P\simeq k[x,y]_{(x)}/(x)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: In fact, $IR_P=PR_P$, and $R_P/PR_P\simeq Q(R/P)$, the field of fractions of $R/P$.

Comment: After giving it some though I realized maybe Womm is wrong in the answer below. How can $y^2$ be both a zero-divisor and invertible? Which one is true? I'm sorry, I'm very confused right now.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $k[x,y]/(xy^2,x^2y)$ has the zero divisor $y^2$ since it becomes zero after multiplying it with the non-zero element $x$. In particular it is also a zero divisor after inverting at the prime ideal $(x)$. Since $k[x]$ is a domain it can not be isomorphic to $(k[x,y]/(xy^2,x^2y))_{(x)}$.

$\textbf{Edit:}$ I think the ring collapses since $y^2\notin(x)$ and therefore will be inverted.

Comment: I can't understand how this answers the question and how $y$, which becomes invertible after localization, is still a zero-divisor.